# How to integrate my Wordpress blog with the new Facebook for Wordpress plugin?

Tags: facebook

The problem I have is related to submitting the actions types for review and approval by Facebook. When I press Submit for the action "Publish" I get the following error message:

> "Built-in Action Types require that you provide instructions for using your app's Open Graph integration as your Open Graph Test User in a functioning test environment. Failure to provide a functioning test environment will result in rejection of your Action Type "<<

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should raise this topic on the official plugin support page. http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/facebook